# regex in python 2

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I have this snippet of a code..

```
(r'^-?[0-9]+(.[0-9]+)?$', 'CD')
```

which is obviously a regular expression. But I can't interpret its meaning?...what is it referring to?

Comment: See https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/tag/sequential.py#L501

Answer (score 0):

Please use a online regex tester like https://regex101.com/ there are also explanations for the different parts of the regex.

Answer (score 0):

regex101.com is one site that explains regular expressions.  You can run tests or provide examples to gain better understanding, too.  Here's a link to your example: https://regex101.com/r/l53cFn/2